# socket.io connected but refuses to emit

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i have a problem with socket io it is connected and i can read both connected and disconnected event but i can't emit from both server nor the client side. emit just doesn't work.

i always worked with socket io in the past year this is the first time it happens

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can You share more frontend code? Everything here seems fine. Also, try adding a callback or any message from the frontend and listen to it on the server.

Comment: If it is refuse to emit can you share error message

Comment: there is no error message that's the problem it is connected and everything but doesn't emit